# Does the Orc's berserker ability work for spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tested this and my initial observation was that it doesn't.

However, I only used the starting destruction spell flames as I didnt want to progress too far before finding out my Orc Mage was not viable. Using flames made it difficult to see if a 2x bonus was occurring.

Am I correct in assuming the berserker ability does not affect spells?

Comment: It would surprise me. Magic is traditionally not an Orc's forte, and berserking shouldn't improve magic (nor damage dealt with magic).

Answer (score 3):

The strategy guide confirms that it does not affect spells (emphasis mine):

> Berserk: For 60 seconds, you take half damage, and inflict double damage in **melee combat.**

Melee combat consisting of one-handed and two-handed weapons, *not* spells or bows.

Answer (score 0):

Berserk works with bows. I just tested it with a plain old not enchanted bow and a bear.

I do not know about berserk with magic, summon, or enchanted weapons.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, which was about spells, not bows.

Answer (score 0):

It works for Bows and any Melee Damage (Including Conjuration Weapons).
It increases your Physical Defense, but Magic resistance does not apply